# Simple Injector Diagnostic Warning Disposable Transient

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I am trying to configure simple injector to work, but I can't seem to get pass this. I followed the instructions on how to fix this in this [link](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/disposabletransientcomponent.html) but it didn't work. Here is the error message:

> NotificationEntities is registered as transient, but implements
>   IDisposable.

Here is the code to the SimpleInjectorInitializer.cs

```
public static void Initialize()
{
    var container = new Container();
    container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new WebRequestLifestyle();

    InitializeContainer(container);

    container.RegisterMvcControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

    container.Verify();

    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver(container));
}

private static void InitializeContainer(Container container)
{
    container.Register<IEmailTemplateRepository, EmailTemplateRepository>();
}
```

The NotificationEntities is generated from EF so it should already implement that, correct?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> The NotificationEntities is generated from EF so it should already implement that, correct?

Yes, `NotificationEntities` does implement `IDisposable`, and this is exactly what the warning is [telling](https://simpleinjector.org/diadt) you:

> *A registration has been made with the Transient lifestyle for a component that implements IDisposable.*

This is a problem because:

> *A component that implements `IDisposable` would usually need deterministic clean-up but Simple Injector does not implicitly track and dispose components registered with the transient lifestyle.*

To fix this you should:

> *Register the component with the scoped lifestyle that is appropriate for the application you are working on.*

In other words, register your `NotificationEntities` as follows:

```
container.Register<NotificationEntities>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
```

Comment: Awesome, that did it. I appreciate the explanations for this!

Comment: @Steven i did the same but for me it says Transient component is registered as transient but implements IDisposable any idea?

Comment: @Arie: You should register it with the `Scoped` lifestyle. If this doesn't work, please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on Stack Overflow and tag with the `simple-injector` tag. I get notified by Stack Overflow anytime someone posts a new Simple Injector question.