# Controller is registered as transient, but implements IDisposable

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, simple-injector

```
var container = new Container();

container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new AsyncScopedLifestyle();

container.RegisterInstance<IDbConnection>(new SqlConnection(connectionString));

container.Register<IAdvertRepository, AdvertRepository>(Lifestyle.Scoped);

container.Register<IAdvertService, AdvertService>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
container.Register<ICommentService, CommentService>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
container.Register<IRoleService, RoleService>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
container.Register<IUserService, UserService>(Lifestyle.Scoped);

container.RegisterWebApiControllers(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);

container.Verify();
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver =
    new SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
```

I'm using Simple Injector in Web API and try to work with it, but get error:

> AdvertController is  registered as transient, but implements IDisposable

Other controllers have the same errors.

How should I fix it?

```
public class AdvertController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IAdvertService _advertService;

    public AdvertController(IAdvertService advertService)
    {
        _advertService = advertService;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<AdvertDto> GetAll()
    {
        return _advertService.GetAll();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public AdvertDto Get(long id)
    {
        return _advertService.Get(id);
    }

    [HttpDelete]
    public void Delete(long id)
    {
        _advertService.Delete(id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `AdvertController` a Web API controller? Please post its code.

Comment: Yes, I added it's code to question

Comment: Please check documentation of Simple Injectior: [http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/disposabletransientcomponent.html](http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/disposabletransientcomponent.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple Injector Diagnostic Warning Disposable Transient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42591234/simple-injector-diagnostic-warning-disposable-transient)

Comment: Not related to your current issue but `container.RegisterInstance<IDbConnection>(new SqlConnection(connectionString));` is *screaming* wrong to me. You seem to be saying that a single connection object can be used for *all* requests - but connections aren't safe to share across multiple threads. Unless you're building an application that is only accessed by a single user at a time (and they limit themselves to a single request at a time), this is going to have issues.

Comment: @Fabio Don't think this is a duplicate. As I see it, the question is: "Why is Simple Injector throwing 'transient, but implements IDisposable', while I registered my controllers using RegisterWebApiControllers".

Comment: And from that perspective, there is something going on that the given examples don't show, because _any Web API controller, registered using `RegisterWebApiControllers`, will suppress this error_.

Comment: @Кириллка, there is crucial information missing that allows anyone to reproduce the issue. Please create a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In other words, post the minimal amount of code that reproduces the problem. You can do this by creating a new and empty Web API project and add registrations until you are able to reproduce the issue. After that try to remove all unnecessary lines of code (by testing whether the issue still holds) and post that. Without this, I’m afraid this question needs to be closed.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else coming to this page, in our case SimpleInjector was automatically updated from 3.1.1 to 4.3.0 because another package had a dependency on the newer version, which broke our MVC5 app with

> XXXController is registered as transient, but implements IDisposable

After some investigating I realized that while the **SimpleInjector** was updated, none of the other related packages (**SimpleInjector.Integration.Web**, **SimpleInjector.Integration.Web.Mvc**, etc.) had been. I updated those, and also had to change all instances of

```
container.RegisterPerWebRequest<T>(...)
```

to

```
container.Register<T>(..., Lifestyle.Scoped)
```

After that everything worked again.

P.S. For anyone noting that the other package should not have had a dependency on SimpleInjector, you are totally correct. It was an internally produced package that had somehow accidentally had the dependency added. We removed it but also thought it was a good idea to get up to the latest SI package.